# Return element value in same path as other elements with same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-attribute

I am currently developing a parser that reads xml and returns specific values into documents.
I have a strange bit of XML that I am not sure how to deal with. Here is an example:

```
<record>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveStartTime">15/08/2014</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveEndTime">31/12/9999</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonProduct">Gen</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonType">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.premium">21.70</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.displayOrder">2</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.replaceAddonType">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonCode">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.status">Live</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.cancellationRefund">00</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveStartTime">15/08/2014</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveEndTime">31/12/9999</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonProduct">Gen</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonType">Bd 1</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.premium">35.85</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.displayOrder">4</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.replaceAddonType">Breakdown</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonCode">Bd 1</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.status">Live</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.cancellationRefund">00</field>
<field name="acceptanceType">tacitCard</field>
<field name="Type">default</field>
<field name="effectiveDate">17/08/2014 00:00:00 BST</field>
<field name="expiryDate">16/08/2015 23:59:59 BST</field>
<field name="creationDate">15/08/2014 13:27:52 BST</field>
<field name="acceptanceDate">15/08/2014 13:43:27 BST</field>
#other elements follow this format
</record>
```

Contained in this sample are two add-ons. I would like to use the addonType field to specify if the add-on is present, and if so, display the related premium.

The add-ons are not separated into parent elements. The sample i have provided is everything I get. So how would I choose between the two premium elements of identical name and path?

If it helps, the elements would always be in the same order, but I would like to avoid using that incase it is changed in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Give us an example of output.

Comment: my output is a word document, formatted into a letter. I use Xpath to merge the fields into the templates. Ill add the full root element onto the sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it helps, the elements would always be in the same order, but I would like to avoid using that incase it is changed in the future.

From your sample the ordering appears to be the only thing grouping related elements - the sequence of elements from one `effectiveStartTime` to the first following `cancellationRefund` constitutes one group, the next group starts with the next `effectiveStartTime`, etc.

I suppose an alternative interpretation if you know the set of field *names* is fixed, would be to iterate over all instances of one particular field name, then pull out the related fields by position, i.e.

```
<xsl:for-each select="field[@name='Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveStartTime']">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  <addon>
    <effectiveStart><xsl:value-of select="."/></effectiveStart>
    <effectiveEnd>
      <xsl:value-of select="
        ../field[@name='Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveEndTime'][$pos]" />
    </effectiveEnd>
    <!-- and so on for the other field names -->
  </addon>
</xsl:for-each>
```

so for the *n*th `effectiveStartTime` you pull out the *n*th `effectiveEndTime`, etc.  This would allow for the fields to appear in any interleaving, as long as the ordering between fields of the same name is consistent, e.g.

```
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveStartTime">15/08/2014</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveStartTime">15/08/2014</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveEndTime">31/12/9999</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.effectiveEndTime">31/12/9999</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonProduct">Gen</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonProduct">Gen</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonType">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonType">Bd 1</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.premium">21.70</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.premium">35.85</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.displayOrder">2</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.displayOrder">4</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.replaceAddonType">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.replaceAddonType">Breakdown</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonCode">ProtectPlus</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.addonCode">Bd 1</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.status">Live</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.status">Live</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.cancellationRefund">00</field>
<field name="Agreement_Role:addonSection.cancellationRefund">00</field>
```

would give the same result.

Comment: Thank you, excellent way of using indices. I have implemented this into a transform and it is working. I will leave this for an hour or two to see if there is another way, then accept. Thank you very much